# Regex stop after first match

Tags: regex

I am using this regular expression which is working well

`^.*\[Ticket ID\: \#(\d*)\].*$`

But when the string looks like this, I only want to get the first value and it's picking up the last one.

`[Ticket ID: #12345] test [Ticket ID: #54321] test2`

I added `?` to the regex, but it doesn't make any difference

`^.*\[Ticket ID\: \#(\d*?)\].*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `^.*` at the beginning is greedy, so it will match as much as it can while still allowing the rest of the regexp to match. If you change that to `^.*?` you'll get the first match.

But you don't actually need to match anything before the ticket number at all. Just use

```
\[Ticket ID: #(\d*)\]
```

There's also no need to escape `:` or `#`, they have no special meaning in regular expressions.
This will return the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *lazy-quantifier* for the first *quantifier*.

```
^.*?\[Ticket ID\: \#(\d*)\].*$
```

Alternately, use a *match pattern*.

```
(?<=\[Ticket ID: #)\d*(?=\])
```